# "Find Similar results" Fast search for sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-part, search-results, fast-for-sharepoint, query

I trying to implement "find similar results" in fast search for sharepoint 2010.
Im using the docvector manage property and similarTo property(KeywordQuery property) for this.
I hv to pass the docvector value of the result to the Query.But i dont know how ...?
Can any1 help me to pass this manage property value to the Query.

link: Find Similar
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521597.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the KeywordQuery class, here is a snippet that should get you what you want:

```
    // instantiate a KeywordQuery object first

    keywordQuery.SimilarType = SimilarType.Find;

    // I'm just using some example values here to ilustrate the usage of the SimilarTo property.    
    keywordQuery.SimilarTo ="[social services, 1][interior renovations, 1][ministry, 0.707107]";                
    keywordQuery.SortSimilar = true;                        
    keywordQuery.QueryText = "projectnumber=12345";

    // perform the query
    ResultTableCollection keywordQuerySearchResults = keywordQuery.Execute();
```