# Work around for implementing Find Similar results in SharePoint 2016

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search, 2016

Environment is SP On-premises 2016 and we are using search.

One of our requirement is to show the users similar results. / Find Similar results.

So want to know how we can achieve this via alternatives.

Also gone through below thread. 
[thread 1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47436/find-similar-results-fast-search-for-sharepoint-2010) 
[thread 2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47436/find-similar-results-fast-search-for-sharepoint-2010)

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per Microsoft it looks like they have removed this feature in the SP 2013 and later versions.

[Changes from SP2010 to SP2013 technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742.aspx)